# T4 Visual studio 2010 Warning Error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, t4

when I want to save a T4 template Visual studio return me this warning below:
[image: Warning]

What does this mean?

Visual Studio 2010 (installed service pack)
Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: I'm thinking my edit is actually what you were wondering; your original question wasn't a question at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T4 templates are scripts that are executed; essentially, they are like any other application on your machine, except they are not signed binaries.  They run under the same user rights as the account that is running Visual Studio.  Hypothetically, I could send you a T4 template that (if you don't run as a normal user) could spawn other processes, delete all files under your Documents folder, and turn your development machine into my own personal SMTP server.

The warning is there to remind people that copypaste template code from a random blog that, yes, if someone wanted to do you harm, they could slip some malicious code in a T4 template and sucker you into running it for them on your machine.

Comment: so currently  i diden't add anything to my T4 template . you advice was pretty , thank you. at all there is no problem to save my own templates with no attentions to visual studio warnings .

Comment: @shaahin: As long as you know this is a possibility, and are careful when using other people's code in your T4 templates, you can safely ignore this warning.  Oh, *and you're Running as a Normal User, right???*

Comment: Hmmmm , i logged in as Administrator to Windows and i did run Visual studio usually (without running it as administrator) have i to run it as administrator ?

Comment: @shaahin: No, you should **NOT** run as administrator when developing.  You should be [running as a normal user](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crathjen/archive/2004/10/26/248030.aspx).  Not only does this help you ensure your application won't be running roughshod on user's machines (doing bad things), it also protects you from things like rogue T4 template code.